# while-loop read only first line from file

Tags: c, while-loop, strtok

Welcome, I have problem with my while-loop. It only reads first line from file.txt. Before adding funcition to split my line by strtok_r ,my apps doesnt work good.The purpose of this while-loop is reads all line from file and split everysingle line by "|" and these parts add to appropriate tabs.
What should i do?
Its my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <mem.h>
#include <assert.h>

struct movie {
    char title[100];
    int year;
    char genre[100];
};

int i = 0;
struct movie *movies[50];



int porownaj(struct movie* first, struct movie* second)
{
    if(first->year==second->year){
            if(first->title>second->title){
                return 1;
            }
            if(first->title<second->title){
                return -1;
            }
            if(first->title==second->title){
                    if(first->genre>second->genre){
                        return 1;
                    }
                    if(first->genre<second->genre){
                        return -1;
                    }
                    if(first->genre==second->genre){
                        return 0;
                    }
            }
    }
    if(first->year>second->year){
        return 1;
    }
    if(first->year<second->year){
        return -1;
    }

    if(first->title==second->title){
        if(first->year>second->year){
                return 1;
            }
            if(first->year<second->year){
                return -1;
            }
            if(first->year==second->year){
                    if(first->genre>second->genre){
                        return 1;
                    }
                    if(first->genre<second->genre){
                        return -1;
                    }
                    if(first->genre==second->genre){
                        return 0;
                    }
            }
    }
    if(first->title>second->title){
        return 1;
    }
    if(first->title<second->title){
        return -1;
    }

    if(first->genre==second->genre){
        if(first->year>second->year){
                return 1;
            }
            if(first->year<second->year){
                return -1;
            }
            if(first->year==second->year){
                    if(first->title>second->title){
                        return 1;
                    }
                    if(first->title<second->title){
                        return -1;
                    }
                    if(first->title==second->title){
                        return 0;
                    }
            }
    }
    if(first->genre>second->genre){
        return 1;
    }
    if(first->genre<second->genre){
        return -1;
    }

}


void zamien(struct movie* movies[50], int x, int y)
{
    struct movie* tmpMovie = movies[x];
    movies[x] = movies[y];
    movies[y] = tmpMovie;
}

int main()
{

    struct movie *movies[50];
    do
    {
        printf("\n");
        printf("Projekt nr 6 \n");
        printf("\n");
        printf("\b   MENU GLOWNE \n");
        printf("|-----------------| \n");
        printf("[1]Baza filmow \n");
        printf("[2]Dodaj film \n");
        printf("[3]Zakoncz Program \n");
        printf("|-----------------| \n");

        char znak;

        printf("Wybierz opcje z menu: ");
        scanf("%s", &znak);

        system("cls");

        switch (znak)
        {
        case '1':
            system("cls");
            printf("Wybrales opcje BAZA FILMOW \n");
            printf("TYTUL | ROK |  GATUNEK\n");
            printf("----------------------\n");

            FILE *baza;
            if ((baza = fopen("movies.txt", "r")) == NULL)
            {
                system("cls");
                printf("Blad otwarcia pliku\n");
                exit(1);
            }

            char tekst[512];

            char *title    = NULL;
            char *year     = NULL;
            char *genre    = NULL;

            char *buffer  = NULL;
            int x         = 0;

            while (fgets(tekst, 512, baza) != NULL)
            {
                printf("%s", tekst);

                title   = strtok_r(tekst, "|", &buffer);
                assert(title != NULL);
                strcpy(movies[x]->title, title);

                year     = strtok_r(NULL, "|", &buffer);
                assert(year != NULL);
                movies[x]->year = atoi(year);

                genre = strtok_r(NULL, "|", &buffer);
                assert(genre != NULL);
                strcpy(movies[x]->genre, genre);

                x++;


            }fclose(baza);


            do
            {
                printf("\n[1]Sortuj wg. tytulu");
                printf("\n[2]Sortuj wg. roku produkcji");
                printf("\n[3]Sortuj wg. gatunku filmu");
                printf("\n[4]Wroc do glownego menu\n");
                printf("|-----------------|\n");

                char click;

                printf("\nWybierz opcje: ");

                scanf("%s", &click);

                switch (click)
                {
                case '1':
                    system("cls");
                    printf("Sorotowanie wg. tytulu");
/*
                    for(int i=0;i<10-1;i++){
                                for(int j=0;j<10-i-1;j++){
                                    if(porownaj(&title[j],&title[j+1])>0){
                                        zamien(&title[j],&title[j+1]);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                                for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
                                    printf("(%d, %d)", title[i].x, );
                                }
*/
                    break;
                case '2':
                    system("cls");
                    printf("Sorotowanie wg. roku produkcji");
/*
                    for(int i=0;i<10-1;i++){
                                for(int j=0;j<10-i-1;j++){
                                    if(porownaj(&year[j],&year[j+1])>0){
                                        zamien(&year[j],&year[j+1]);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                                for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
                                    printf("(%d, %d)", year[i].x, );
                                }
*/
                    break;
                case '3':
                    system("cls");
                    printf("Sorotowanie wg. gatunku filmu");

                    break;
                case '4':
                    system("cls");
                    return main();
                default:
                    system("cls");
                    printf("Nie ma takiej opcji. Program sie wylaczy!");
                    return 0;
                }
            } while (1);

        case '2':
            system("cls");
            printf("Wybrales opcje DODAJ FILM \n");

            movies[i] = malloc(sizeof(movie));

            printf("Podaj nazwe filmu: ");
            while ((getchar()) != '\n');
            gets(movies[i]->title);

            printf("Podaj rok produkcji: ");
            scanf("%d", &(movies[i]->year));

            printf("Podaj gatunek filmu: ");
            while ((getchar()) != '\n');

            gets(movies[i]->genre);

            fflush(stdin);

            FILE *plik = fopen("movies.txt", "a+");
            fprintf(plik, "%s | %d | %s \n", movies[i]->title, movies[i]->year, movies[i]->genre);
            fclose(plik);
            i++;
            printf("Zapisane..");
            continue;
        case '3':
            system("cls");
            printf("ZAKONCZ PROGRAM \n");
            return 0;
        default:
            printf("Nie ma takiej opcji! \n");
            return main();
        }
        }while (1);

return (0);
}
```

movies.txt:

```
Title | 1234 | Scifi
Title_2 | 4321 | SciFI
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please try to create a [mcve] to show us.

Comment: `title=movies[x]->title;` Did you mean `movies[x]->title = title;` ? But even that would be wrong...

Comment: Please work on that question checkist provided by Some.

Comment: i tryed to find any solution to this problem but i couldn't :(

Comment: Start by showing us the contents of the input file.

Comment: Do the program crash? (tip: add a printf after the while loop)

Comment: Is `x` initialized to zero? How is `movies` defined? You need to show us more code.

Comment: Change `char title;` to `char *title;` etc.

Comment: And what would `int year = atoi(year);` mean??

Comment: To change char on int

Comment: There is a chance the `int year=` masks the `char *year;` Less confusing to use different names.

Comment: `char title    = NULL;` --> `char *title    = NULL;` and this appliy to the next lines as well

Comment: ok but it only reads one line

Comment: what is the second code block?

Comment: You still haven't shown us the input file...

Comment: it function to add title , year and genre to my file txt

Comment: Do u need my file.txt?

Comment: We need movies.txt !

Comment: @PabloKwiatkowski Please answer these questions. a) Have you tried to put a print statement after the while-loop and did it print? b) Do your program crash? c) What is the contents of the file movies.txt?

Comment: A) Yes and it didn't print anything :( 
b) No , only one line and nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of bugs in your program.

To start with this:

```
        char title    = NULL;
        char year     = NULL;
        char genre    = NULL;
```

together with this:

```
        title   = strtok_r(tekst, "|", &buffer);
        year     = strtok_r(NULL, "|", &buffer);
        genre = strtok_r(NULL, "|", &buffer);
        int year = atoi(year);
```

You define `title` as a `char` but `strtok_r` returns a `char*`. Consequently you overwrite memory by storing a "char pointer" in a "char" variable.
 This could destroy the file-pointer. The error 0xC0000005 you get (as you mention in a comment) could indicate that:

> Application Error 0xc0000005 (Access Violation) error is usually caused by your computer not being able to correctly process the files...

Change the definition to:

```
        char *title    = NULL;
        char *year     = NULL;
        char *genre    = NULL;
```

Further:

```
        year     = strtok_r(NULL, "|", &buffer);  // A variable named year
        genre = strtok_r(NULL, "|", &buffer);
        int year = atoi(year);                    // A NEW variable with same name!!
```

Change it to:

```
        year     = strtok_r(NULL, "|", &buffer);
        genre = strtok_r(NULL, "|", &buffer);
        int yearN = atoi(year);                // Use another name
```

Further you should always check that `year` is **not** NULL before calling `atoi`

So my suggestion is to simplify your code for debugging. Try:

```
        FILE *baza;
        if ((baza = fopen("movies.txt", "r")) == NULL)
        {
            system("cls");
            printf("Blad otwarcia pliku\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        char tekst[512];
        char* title    = NULL;
        char* year     = NULL;
        char* genre    = NULL;
        char* buffer  = NULL;
        int x         = 0;
    printf("while-loop start\n");
    while (fgets(tekst, 512, baza) != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s", tekst);
        //x++;

        //title   = strtok_r(tekst, "|", &buffer);
        //year     = strtok_r(NULL, "|", &buffer);
        //genre = strtok_r(NULL, "|", &buffer);
        //int year = atoi(year);

        //title=movies[x]->title;
        //year=movies[x]->year;
        //genre=movies[x]->genre;

    }
    printf("while-loop complete\n");
```

Now check the output you get from this code. If that works as expected, you can start to un-comment lines one-by-one.

In the end I guess your function should look like:

```
        FILE *baza;
        if ((baza = fopen("movies.txt", "r")) == NULL)
        {
            system("cls");
            printf("Blad otwarcia pliku\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        char tekst[512];
        char* title    = NULL;
        char* year     = NULL;
        char* genre    = NULL;
        char* buffer  = NULL;
        int x         = 0;

    while (fgets(tekst, 512, baza) != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s", tekst);

        title   = strtok_r(tekst, "|", &buffer);
        assert(title != NULL);
        strcpy(movies[x]->title, title);            

        year     = strtok_r(NULL, "|", &buffer);
        assert(year != NULL);
        movies[x]->year = atoi(year);

        genre = strtok_r(NULL, "|", &buffer);
        assert(genre != NULL);
        strcpy(movies[x]->genre, genre);            

        x++;
    }
```

The above assumes that you have already allocated memory for all pointers in `movies`. Like:

```
struct movie { char title[100]; int year; char genre[100]; }; 

int main() {
    int i = 0; 
    struct movie *movies[50];
    for(i=0; i<50; ++i) movies[i] = malloc(sizeof *movies);
    . . .
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187082/discussion-on-answer-by-4386427-while-loop-read-only-first-line-from-file).

Answer (score 1):

I bet that every line is printed with `printf("%s", tekst);`.

But you forget that `strtok` does *not* make a copy of the string. Thus (if you have your assignments fixed the other way around), you still assign poinetrs into the same `tekst` variable to all your movies. Instead allocate memory and copy the strings:

```
    title   = strtok_r(tekst, "|", &buffer);
    movies[x]->title= malloc(strlen(title)+1);
    strcpy(movies[x]->title, title);
```

and the same for the other string variables.

Comment: Or simply use `strdup()` if available (almost anywhere)

Comment: yes, like I did in my answer some minutes before ^^

Comment: See the comments to your question for more bugs.

Comment: But `tekst` is read using `fgets` before each new print so I can't see how this explains that only one line is printed in the loop

Comment: Turn warnings of your compiler on. There are some problems (bugs) that may upset the program. For example, assigning a pointer to a char.

Comment: Now, i have this problem " |error: assignment to expression with array type|"

Answer (score 0):

out of any other possible problems these lines are problematic :

```
    title=movies[x]->title;
    year=movies[x]->year;
    genre=movies[x]->genre;
```

- as it is said in remark the assignments must be reversed ( `movies[x]->foo = foo;`)
- you need to duplicate the strings else you save a sub addresses of *tekst* which is modified each loop and may be disappeared when you will use them

so

```
    movies[x]->title = strdup(title);
    movies[x]->year = year;
    movies[x]->genre = strdup(genre);
```

Or course if `movies[x]->title` and `movies[x]->genre` are `char[]` rather than `char*` the code have to copy rather than duplicate :

```
    strcpy(movies[x]->title, title);
    movies[x]->year = year;
    strcpy(movies[x]->genre, genre);
```

and if needed replace *strcpy* by *strncpy* to not overflow

Comment: @PabloKwiatkowski are you saying movies[x]->title and movies[x]->genre are char[] rather than char * ?

Comment: i have to check it

Comment: they are char[]

Comment: @PabloKwiatkowski ok, so look at the strcpy, I just edited my answer

Comment: @PabloKwiatkowski and what appends ? a crash ?

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question

Comment: @4386427 what do you mean ? we have almost no infos, the given code cannot compile etc, I just speak about the visible problems, and as you can see Paul said the same things few minutes after me

Comment: The question is about "only reading one line from the file" - I don't see this answer addressing that

Comment: @4386427 I don't see any answer at all from you ;-)

Comment: I don't answer because I don't know what the answer is... I can see several bugs in the code but none that explains the behavior OP describes

Comment: @4386427 I am afraid we can just ask to close that question because not enough material and given material is wrong

Comment: @PabloKwiatkowski What do you mean by "... and then nothing happens" ?

Comment: app shows me only this after this one line" 
Process returned -1073741819 (0xC0000005)   execution time : 3.141 s
Press any key to continue.
"